# Sleeve and cotter joint

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing, machine-design

What does 0.1D  signify in this cotter joint. I meant is it denotes spacing between pin and hole. I am new to machine drawing , kindly let me know. Thanks in advance[image: cotter joint]

Comment: Can you include the source of this image - the website or PDF?

Answer (score 2):

That is just clearance between the Cotter and the Socket/Spigot.

The Cotter pushes only one one side of the slot that it is fitted into, so there should be clearance on the opposite side to ensure this.

"D" = the last two digits of the roll number, as shown at the bottom right.

The image below is taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sUjb-uQwOI which should clear things up conceptually for you

[image]